# Getting AttributeError: sender while iterating to get specific values

Tags: django, exchangelib

Getting "AttributeError: sender" is thrown as the exchange query iterates. Same with other values (message_id, etc) too. My only option at this point is to put a try/catch around it and need to refactor a lot of content under the loop. However, I would think the query should not be crashing under normal circumstances due to any data issue. Please let me know what could be going wrong. There appears to be a 'bad' email object that causes it?

```
kwargs = {"is_read": False}
kwargs["datetime_received__gt"] = some_date_time

filtered_items = my_exchange._service_account.inbox.filter(**kwargs)
filtered_items.page_size = 20

print(filtered_items.count())

3     <-- 3 objects

for sender_obj, msg_id, msg_subj, msg_text, msg_size in filtered_items.values_list("sender", "message_id", "subject", "text_body", "size").iterator():
    print(sender_obj)
    count = count + 1
    print(count)


Mailbox(name='Some User1', email_address='someuser1@myemail.acme', routing_type='SMTP', mailbox_type='Mailbox')
1
Mailbox(name='Some User2', email_address='someuser2@myemail.acme', routing_type='SMTP', mailbox_type='OneOff')
2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/exchangelib/queryset.py", line 273, in __iter__
    yield from self._format_items(items=self._query(), return_format=self.return_format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/exchangelib/queryset.py", line 352, in _item_yielder
    yield item_func(i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/exchangelib/queryset.py", line 380, in <lambda>
    item_func=lambda i: tuple(f.get_value(i) for f in self.only_fields),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/exchangelib/queryset.py", line 380, in <genexpr>
    item_func=lambda i: tuple(f.get_value(i) for f in self.only_fields),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/exchangelib/fields.py", line 189, in get_value
    return getattr(item, self.field.name)
AttributeError: sender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get the `sender` field of something that is not a Message. Probably your inbox contains a meeting request or some other non-message object.

I'm not sure this is a bug. What did you expect to be the result of getting the `sender` attribute of something that does not have a `sender` field?

If you want only Message objects in your list, you can try adding a filter on `item_class='IPF.Note'`.

Comment: Basically like most other django models I use, I was assuming the fields of a given table to be present in all records unless there is any deprecation. I did not expect message_id and sender to be absent. So I had not accounted for such scenario in my implementation. The IPF.Note filter is sounds great. I will use it. However, I wonder whether this should be handled at the exchange query side to be uniform since the standard facility of value_list can break as in my case. Thank you.

Comment: It's a false premise that an exchange folder is backed by a table. It's not, at least not in the sense that all "rows" have the same shape. exchangelib makes this assumption too. It works surprisingly well mostly, but sometimes it fails, like in this case.

Comment: That said, I do think raising AttributeError is a bit weird. Also, it's not trivial to work around as a user when using `values()` or `values_list()`, and `only()` does not behave like this. https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/commit/57dffb37ef2b4c2d6f1353144faac730ec688baf should fix this for you.

Comment: My query to remove non-messages worked only with {.....   'item_class': 'IPM.Note'}  not with 'IPF.Note' . (Thought it is a typo (still could be), but then a search for IPF.Note in the exchange lib repo showed up some hits. Cannot find any documentation reference at MSDN too.) If possible kindly add a filter example using  'item_class': 'IPM.Note in the query at https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/ for anyone needing.